# Displaying 2 ViewModels using caliburn.micro

Tags: c#, caliburn.micro

I am looking to display 2 controls on the screen at the same time and allow them to transition independently from one another. I am using a Conductor.Collection.AllActive but cannot figure out how to get the List control (a screen called ProductListViewModel) and the detail screen (ProductViewModel) to show up at the same time in the shell.

How do I get them to load into the appropriate ContentControls?

```
    <mah:TransitioningContentControl Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" 
        Margin="5"                             
        x:Name="NavigationFrame"/>

    <mah:TransitioningContentControl Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" Margin="5" 
        x:Name="ContentFrame" />
```

Comment: Could you post your `ViewModel` side? This is only the `XAML`.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out and think it is actually very simple. The ViewModel needs an IScreen property per content area in which you want to place an independent view.

So, in this case, it would be

```
public class ShellViewModel: Screen
{
    private string _title = "Some title";
    private Conductor<IScreen> _listConductor;
    private Conductor<IScreen> _detailConductor;

    public ShellViewModel()
    {
        _listConductor = new Conductor<IScreen>();
        _detailConductor = new Conductor<IScreen>();

        ListFrame = GetContainer().Resolve<ProductListViewModel>();
        DetailFrame = GetContainer().Resolve<ProductViewModel>();
    }

    public string Title { get => _title; set => _title = value; }

    public IScreen ListFrame
    {
        get { return _listConductor.ActiveItem; }
        set {
            _listConductor.ActivateItem(value);
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(nameof(ListFrame));
        }
    }

    public IScreen DetailFrame
    {
        get { return _detailConductor.ActiveItem; }
        set {
            _detailConductor.ActivateItem(value);
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(nameof(DetailFrame));
        }
    }
```

etc.